# Matlab - printing multiple variables

Tags: matlab, printf, disp

I am trying to print multiple variables to the command window with accompanying text. disp does not seem to want to work, nor does fprintf. Does anyone have any idea how i can do this. I am trying to print code to look like the following, inserting variables in between text

```
print('The minimum value is', minY1(2), 'which occurs at x = ', minX);
```

which would, for example, result in

The minimum value is 69.054, which occurs at x = 5

Cheers

Comment: What about `` didn't work?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
fprintf('The minimum value is %d which occurs at x = %d', minY1(2), minX);
```

`%d` is used for numbers and `%s` would be used for strings.

Answer (score 0):

disp probably didn't produce what you want because you need to explicitly convert the numbers to text.  You can try:

```
disp(['The minimum value is ' num2str(minY1(2)) ', which occurs at x = ' num2str(minX)]);
```